# django link button works in safari but not in firefox

Tags: html, css

```
class A(models.Model):
.....
....
  def link_method(self):
        return "<a href='path_to_link/%s'><input type='submit' value='Label'></a>" % (self.id)
```

The link on button `Label` works fine in safari, but in firefox nothing happens. when hovering over the button the link path shows correctly at the bottom.

The link is to a `view`. When clicking the button on firefox, the view is not reached while safari everything is ok. Therefore I am assuming there is some problem in the method.

Can some one point out the problem????

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you add some more info, e.g. what's the error and where does the anchor link refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` tags need to be within a `<form>` tag; otherwise you are dealing with non-standard HTML. The problem with non-standard HTML is that the behavior is not defined; browsers are free to have their own implementation choices for non-standard HTML.

I suggest using the following:

```
def link_method(self):
    return '<form action="path_to_link/%s" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Label"></form>' % (self.id)
```

However, links and buttons have different purposes; if all you want to do is go some other place it is better to keep a `<a>` tag that you can style with css to look like a button. You can do badges and labels easily with libraries such as [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I am just starting to understand HTML. A long way to go........

Comment: Perhaps you can also help me with this. 
I would like the link to open in a new page, can you advice what should be done.
Thanks

Comment: please see the `target` attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp